# Can I go for single or multiple cloud landing pages for more that 40 + custom preference center in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I like to create custom preference center for 40+ different branding-cloud pages ( 90% same style & design ) having the same set of fields to capture data into SFMC DE. I need to change some content(logo & some opt-in for other brands) and add/ remove some of the field based on URL value (key to identify the current brand ). Can I do that in single cloud pages or go for separate pages? or any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put this all on a single page since it is so similar.

I would have a lookup (either to a DE or a passed parameter) on the page that then pulls in the required logo, fields, content, etc.

I would recommend storing the fields, logo, etc inside of individual content blocks and setting them as AMPScript variables - so if they change, you do not need to edit the page itself. You instead just edit the appropriate content area.

via ContentBlockbyKey(): `%%=ContentBlockbyKey("myContentBlock")=%%`

Inside your page, I would set a default value for if lookup is empty or no parameter passed and then just call in the appropriate variables at the locations.

E.g. `<img src="%%=v(@logo)=%%" />`

Comment: Add to that, those content is part of PF center pages like dynamic opt-in for other brands, I need to get those data to upsert in SFMC DE, Can I do that?

Comment: absolutely - you would just set whatever flag/api call/etc you need inside of the content blocks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gortonington. That opt-in for multiple branding in every current PF center pages, opt-in content dynamic, I need to show all other branding except the current one. Can I?

Comment: If you configure it in the parent business unit, you'll need to pass the child's MID along in the URL.  Something like this:  `%%=redirectto(concat(CloudPagesURL(1234),"&mid=",memberid))=%%`

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, I'm going to use only Parent BU. No issue on that. I having separate field set for each branding detail in single SFMC DE. that going to render coresponding field in PF center page dynamically based on current brand.